# When running on Windows Server I get 'unicode error' but on my pc works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

for some reasons when I run my python script on my windows server 2016 i get the error `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape` . 
On my PC works everything just fine.

Lines that I use to execute the program:

```
cmd = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GTA - San Andreas\samp.exe\samp.exe jade.nephrite.ro"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)
process.wait()
```

Comment: whats your pc operating system?

Comment: It could be because the Windows Server has Python 2.7

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It runs Windows 10 Pro.
User8212173, I installed on windows server the python 3.7 version that I also use on my PC.

Comment: In that case, please share the full `Traceback` error and/or supporting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a raw string for `"c:\Users..."`.  The `\U` begins a Unicode escape sequence on Python 3, where strings are default Unicode.

```
>>> print("C:\Users")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>> print(r"C:\Users")
C:\Users
```